# What does compilationOptions.emitEntryPoint mean?

Tags: asp.net-core, project.json

Just installed the rc1 tools and created a new web project to see what has changed in the template.

I noticed that project.json now contains:

```
"compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
}
```

But it's unclear what this does.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As mentioned below: It looks like it is a flag to the compiler to indicate that the project is a console application vs. a library (namely: a console application must contain `public static void Main()`)

You can see from the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.Common/CompilerOptionsExtensions.cs#L70-L71) here.

In the new RC1 default web application template, you'll notice at the bottom of `Startup.cs` there is a new expression bodied method that acts as the entry point:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
```

If you remove this method then perform a build (`dnu build`) you will get an error:

```
error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
```

However, if you change the `emitEntryPoint` flag to `false` and attempt to build again, it will succeed. This is because it is creating a library instead of a console app.

Answer (score 10):

I see this in the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.Common/CompilerOptionsExtensions.cs#L70-L71);

```
var outputKind = compilerOptions.EmitEntryPoint.GetValueOrDefault() ?
    OutputKind.ConsoleApplication : OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary;
```

Looks like it tells the compiler whether to create a Console Application or a Library.

Additionaly, if you create a new Class Library (Package) and Console Application (Package) in VS2015 you'll see that project.json for the Console Application includes the following, while the Class Library does not;

```
"compilationOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true
}
```