# Entrypoint does not get triggering in Asp dotnet 5 web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Hi i have created a web api application in ASP.Net 5. i have set

```
"compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
```

in project.json file. But the following function

```
public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
```

in Startup.cs does not get triggering. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does compilationOptions.emitEntryPoint mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888632/what-does-compilationoptions-emitentrypoint-mean)

Comment: sorry my need is to trigger that entry point in Startup.cs. But its not triggering.

Comment: After changing `emitEntryPoint=true` are you still not getting the Main method triggered?

Comment: yes it is automatically hosted without triggering the entry point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link [ASP.NET 5 Entry point overview](http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/12/24/asp-net-5-entry-point-overview/) gives the solution to trigger entry point in ASP.NET 5 Web Application.
 We can trigger the entry point by adding the following line in project.json file.

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
     "devo": "MyProject --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:5001 --ASPNET_ENV Development",
   },
```

In this code replace **MyProject** by your project name and select this command in debugging option of visual studio.[image]