# Choosing between .dll and .exe in .NET Core in project.json

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

How can I choose between .dll and .exe as output type from project in new project format for .NET Core?

Comment: I wouldn't start getting too worried about project.json at the moment, as it's being deprecated... The .NET Core tooling will eventually only be MSBuild-based.

Answer (score 2):

The option in project.json file is `emitEntryPoint`.

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
}
```

This switches between console application .exe (true) and library .dll (false).

When this option is enabled, the application must have `public static void Main()`.

See: [Answer about `emitEntryPoint` meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888632/what-does-compilationoptions-emitentrypoint-mean)

Comment: Adding `emitEntryPoint` alone is not enough.  If the application is a portable application, no executable file is generated.  If it is a self-contained application, an executable file is generated.  See [.NET Core App Types](https://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/app-types.html).