# What are buildOptions and preserveCompilationContext used for?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, project.json

I am playing with just released ASP.NET Core. I have created new project and I am looking at `project.json`. I'd like to know what is this part of configuration for:

```
"buildOptions": {
   "emitEntryPoint": true,
   "preserveCompilationContext": true
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good answer for emitEntryPoint exists here: [What does compilationOptions.emitEntryPoint mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888632/what-does-compilationoptions-emitentrypoint-mean)

As for preserveCompilationContext the ASP.NET documentation states it needs to be true in order to compile views: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html

Answer (score 13):

**emitEntryPoint** is used to let the compiler know it's an application, not a library. In other words, if `emitEntryPoint = true`, you must have a `public static void Main()`.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#emitEntryPoint):

> Creates an executable if set to true, otherwise the project will produce a `.dll`.

**preserveCompilationContext** isn't documented in the above page (yet), but it's required when you are using Razor or any other type of runtime compiling. Without it, runtime compilation of Razor views will fail.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, ASP.NET Core 1.1,

> "preserveCompilationContext": true

get build time in 9 seconds, after set false, build time get faster, ~1s.

My application is for Web Api only.

ref: [issue version 1.1](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1829)